# How to associate multiple UPNs, email domains, with a single IdP using custom policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to B2C custom policies and have a need to associate multiple UPNs (or email domain names) with the OpenID IdP configured for my corporate Azure Tenant (company1.com).  A majority of my corporate user accounts contain a UPN suffix of first.last@company1.com where "company1.com" is the name of the Azure tenant and domain name.  We have a good number of affiliates configured with a UPN suffix of @company2.com and @company3.com.  These accounts reside in the same tenant as the @company1.com accounts.

How can I associate @company2.com and @company3.com accounts with the same IdP configured for @company1.com?

I tried adding an addition OrchestrationStep and referenced the same TechnicalProfileReferenceID used for company1.com...

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <Preconditions>
     <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
       <Value>domain</Value>
       <Value>company1.com</Value>
       <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
     </Precondition>
   </Preconditions>  
   <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="Company1Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Company1-OpenIdConnect" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>domain</Value>
      <Value>company2.com</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>  
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="Company2Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Company1-OpenIdConnect" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

When attempting to sign in using the custom policy, I receive an error AADB2C99001 "This user already exists, and profile 'AAD-UserUpdateWithUserIdentities' does not allow the same user to be created again."

Our current custom policies were developed by a consultant and I am trying to get up to speed.

The easiest way I can explain the challenge is:

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
  <Value>domain</Value>
    **<Value>company1.com or company2.com or company3.com</Value>**
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
</Precondition>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are using federation i.e. users are logging in with their Azure AD account.

In this case, you need three federations.

Use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery) to sign-in.

"Demonstrates how to implement a sign in journey, where the user is automatically directed to their federated identity provider based off of their email domain. And for users who arrive with an unknown domain, they are redirected to a default identity provider."